# Unable to delete Fragment

Tags: java, android

```
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.array:

            if (fragment != null) {
                Fragment fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(serial,"");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            }
            else {
                Fragment fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(serial,"key2");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.arrayFrame, fragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            }
```

While this - Fragment remaining on the window. I can't remove him fully

After first click - Fragment appear on the window
After second click (Fragment already exist!)  - nothing happened.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Cuz you are checking if fragment exists:

```
if (fragment != null)
```

After that you create a new one  `Fragment fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(serial,"");`
and removing it

If you still need help, post more code.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new instance from the fragment and trying remove another instance which is not added to the fragment manager, keep the fragment object you are adding to fragment manager global and remove this object when you need it